# Autofill dynamic range based on another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've got 2 sheets in a workbook with different sets of data. Sheet 1 has a set of data not formatted as a table. The header row for this data is on Row 4. When I try doing a count using `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`, I get the  last row of that entire sheet, not the count of how many rows of data there are *from my starting point*.

Sheet 2 has its header row in Row 1. So when I try to use the same count of rows I mentioned above to AutoFill, I always get 3 extra rows because the Sheet 1 count is just looking at what the last row of data is.

I don't want to have to shift things around in either sheet. I just want to be able to autofill based on the same number of rows as there are in Sheet 1, beginning the count at A5 and going down to the last row of data. Is there a different count formula to start at a specific cell and only count the rows below it, and then telling the other sheet to only AutoFill *based on that number* that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be over thinking this. Just discount the row count by 3

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 3
```

---

I would qualify the objects & properties (`Range` & `Row`) as well for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

could you use either:

```
set rng = Range("A1:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
```

or

```
set rng = Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Resize(,1)
```

assuming no blanks in the data range